# How to provide JSON data sample on PHP-Swagger

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, swagger-php

currently I'm using Laravel to create an API and Library [DarkaOnline - L5 Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) which based on [PHP-Swagger](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) to create the API Documentation.

My question is how to provide JSON data sample on the swagger?

Currently I can do the thing like this on parameter description:
[image: JSON data sample on Parameter Description]
But there's look so ugly and not to long and make the reader so confuse. Is there any best way to do this?